# Setting value of select2, which uses AJAX, on page load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Is it possible to programmatically select an entry for a `select2` that uses AJAX for its list build, using the entry's id?

I am using a `select2` element in my page to get client information. The `select2` uses AJAX to load the list of client names based on the user typing an input.

Once the user selects the client, I post to back end with client_id and run a search / generate a list of data, which is then loaded onto a new impression of the same page.

I want to pre-select the `select2` with this client_id and have it show the relevant client_name. How do I get the AJAX based `select2` to select this client_id?

My JS and `select2` code is:

```
var resultsArray;
var clientSearch = '{!! $clientSearch !!}';

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#client_id').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        placeholder: 'Select client',
        val: clientSearch,  // TRIED THIS BUT IT DOES NOT WORK
        ajax: {
            url: '{!! route('client.selectList') !!}',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 500,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                resultsArray = data;
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                        return {
                            id: obj.id, text: obj.client_name + ' (' + obj.state + ' ' + obj.postcode + ')'};
                    }),
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 2
    });

});
```

I have tried setting the `val:` (per above) and setting the `select2` value like below without success:

```
if (clientSearch != null) {
    $('#client_id').select2({'val': clientSearch});
}

if (clientSearch != null) {
    $('#client_id').val(clientSearch).trigger("change");
}

if (clientSearch != null) {
    $("#client_id").select2('data', {id: clientSearch, text: clientName});
}
```

I also tried another suggestion such as adding this to the `select2` declaration as follows:

```
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 2
}).val(clientSearch).trigger('change');
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I am trying to get it to search for an id and display its resulting text. I am not understanding how your suggestion will achieve this, sorry.

Comment: Try this - `minimumInputLength: 2
}).select2("val", clientSearch);`

Comment: Bdw.. what's the version of `select2`? Also could you please confirm if `clientSearch` has any value when you try to assign it?

Comment: Hi @Guruprasad Rao, thanks for the help. Your suggestion above did not work here. Yes, I can see that the javascript variable is receiving the correct id (49 in my test case!) as per submitted prior from the `select2`. And the page loads with clientSearch having this value. Select2 is fresh (downloaded it yesterday into my project).

Comment: Could you create a `fiddle` with sample `ajax` call to git file?

Comment: You want to populate your select2 with ajax on page load ?

Comment: Yes. I have an ID, I want it to populate the text for it

Comment: Have you tried to add your parameter inside your data: ajax parameter ? Just below `page: params.page`

Comment: Hi @John, I have not, because I have the id of the client and not the search term, which is essentially the client's name.

Comment: And this `$('#client_id').val(clientSearch).trigger("change");` not working ?

Comment: Hi @John, it is not. I have updated my tries above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122747/discussion-between-john-and-therealpapa).

Answer (score 0):

I got the [answer from here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3057).

```
if (clientSearch != null) {
    $('#client_id').append('<option value="' + clientSearch + '">' + clientName + '</option>');
    $('#client_id').val($('#client_id').val()).trigger('change');
}
```